# What regex can I use to extract the URL from an HTTP <a> element?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the Original string :

```
var str = "<a href=\"https://sjobs.brassring.com/1033/ASP/TG/cim_home.asp?partnerid=25172&amp;siteid=5235&amp;LanguageId=1/javascript:window.location='cim_jobdetail.asp?SID=^cJgiKPhGBHyn5VRSb9gbJg0K2T88FrLqHyAtd6hd5pJ7JeXxNyq0VatKCq3jYWp/&amp;jobId=385594&amp;type=hotjobs&amp;JobReqLang=141&amp;JobSiteId=5239&amp;JobSiteInfo=385594_5239&amp;GQId=0'\"> a vartiable</a>";
```

and I need this part:

```
str = "https://sjobs.brassring.com/1033/ASP/TG/cim_jobdetail.asp?SID=^cJgiKPhGBHyn5VRSb9gbJg0K2T88FrLqHyAtd6hd5pJ7JeXxNyq0VatKCq3jYWp/&amp;jobId=385594&amp;type=hotjobs&amp;JobReqLang=141&amp;JobSiteId=5239&amp;JobSiteInfo=385594_5239&amp;GQId=0";
```

In other words, I need to remove the tag `<a>` and the `document.href value`

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var str = "<a href=\"https://sjobs.brassring.com/1033/ASP/TG/cim_home.asp?partnerid=25172&amp;siteid=5235&amp;LanguageId=1/javascript:window.location='cim_jobdetail.asp?SID=^cJgiKPhGBHyn5VRSb9gbJg0K2T88FrLqHyAtd6hd5pJ7JeXxNyq0VatKCq3jYWp/&amp;jobId=385594&amp;type=hotjobs&amp;JobReqLang=141&amp;JobSiteId=5239&amp;JobSiteInfo=385594_5239&amp;GQId=0'\"> a vartiable</a>";
str.replace(/^<a href="(https.*?)cim_home\.asp.*?'(cim_jobdetail\.asp.*)'.*$/, "$1$2");
```

produces:

```
"https://sjobs.brassring.com/1033/ASP/TG/cim_jobdetail.asp?SID=^cJgiKPhGBHyn5VRSb9gbJg0K2T88FrLqHyAtd6hd5pJ7JeXxNyq0VatKCq3jYWp/&amp;jobId=385594&amp;type=hotjobs&amp;JobReqLang=141&amp;JobSiteId=5239&amp;JobSiteInfo=385594_5239&amp;GQId=0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like the following should work...

```
href="(.*?)"
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the code u want:

```
var str = '<a href="https://sjobs.brassring.com/1033/ASP/TG/cim_home.asp?partnerid=25172&amp;siteid=5235&amp;LanguageId=1/javascript:window.location='cim_jobdetail.asp?SID=^cJgiKPhGBHyn5VRSb9gbJg0K2T88FrLqHyAtd6hd5pJ7JeXxNyq0VatKCq3jYWp/&amp;jobId=385594&amp;type=hotjobs&amp;JobReqLang=141&amp;JobSiteId=5239&amp;JobSiteInfo=385594_5239&amp;GQId=0'"> a vartiable</a>'

var url = /\"(.*?)\"/str
```

that's how you match, here's how you strip it out:

```
str.replace(/\"(.*?)\"/, "$1");
```

the `\"(.*?)\"` gives the first minimal set of characters between two `"` characters the id of `$1` then the second argument to the replace function tells it to replace the whole string with what's contained in `$1`

Also, if you use jQuery, this becomes pretty trivial:

```
var url = $("a").attr("href");
```

Comment: AFAIK the OP doesn't want to get the whole url, but only the first part concatenated with what there is in the window.location =